# get average salary with Java stream api;

Tags: java, java-stream

how can i get the average salary of company employees whose salary is more than salaryLimit?
I think first I need to get a list of all salaries and filter it + use mapToInt and average, but...nothing works((

```
public class TestCl {

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Company {
    private List<Department> departments;
}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Department {
    private List<Employee> employees;
}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Employee {
    private int salary;
}

@Test
public void test() {
    int salaryLimit = 25;

    List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>(){{
        add(new Employee(10));
        add(new Employee(20));
        add(new Employee(30));
        add(new Employee(40));
        add(new Employee(50));
    }};

    List<Department> departments = new ArrayList<>(){{
        add(new Department(employees));
        add(new Department(employees));
        add(new Department(employees));
        add(new Department(employees));
        add(new Department(employees));
    }};

    Company company = new Company(departments);

    float average = company.getDepartments().stream()
            .map(Department::getEmployees).toList().stream()
            .map(Employee::getSalary).toList().stream()
            .filter(x -> x >= salaryLimit).mapToInt().average();

    System.out.println(average);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one thing, you're looking for `Stream.flatMap()`.  For example,

```
company.getDepartments().stream()
            .flatMap(d -> d.getEmployees().stream()) // ...
```

That converts your stream of `Departments` to a stream of the `Employees` of each department.  You can then `map()` those to salaries and filter as you already do.

The combination `.toList().stream()` makes zero sense, however, as it expends work to convert one stream to another one providing exactly the same objects.  Removing that has only upside.

To map to an `IntStream` or, probably better for this purpose, a `DoubleStream`, the `mapToInt()` or `mapToDouble()` method requires a function expressing the details of the mapping, which you are omitting.

Finally, `IntStream.average()`, `DoubleStream.average()`, *etc* return an `OptionalInteger` / `OptionalDouble` / *etc*, which accommodates the possibility that there is no average on account of the stream  providing zero elements.  You need to deal with that.

All together, then:

```
float average = company.getDepartments().stream() // a stream of Departments
        .flatMap(d -> d.getEmployees().stream())  // a stream of Employees
        .map(e -> e.getSalary())                  // a stream of Integer salaries
        .filter(s -> s.intValue() >= salaryLimit) // only the high salaries
        .mapToDouble(Integer::doubleValue)        // as a DoubleStream
        .average()                                // reduce to an average
        .getAsDouble();                           // the value, if it exists
```

Note well that the `getAsDouble()` will throw `NoSuchElementException` if no salaries satisfy the filter criterion.  Catching and handling that is a perfectly reasonable way to deal with the situation, but if you want to avoid that then you can store the result of `average()` instead of chaining `getAsDouble()`, and then test it with `isPresent()` to decide whether to go ahead with `getAsDouble()` or to handle the situation differently.  Or if there is a specific `double` value that you want to provide in that case -- such as `0` or `Double.NaN` -- then you could chain on an `orElse(valueForZeroSalaries)` instead of the `getAsDouble()`.

Comment: now i got it like this ->                                                                                                                 float average = (float) company.getDepartments().stream()
                .map(Department::getEmployees)
                .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                .map(Employee::getSalary)
                .toList()
                .stream().filter(x -> x >= salaryLimit)
                .mapToInt(n -> n).average().getAsDouble();

Comment: thanks, good solution

Comment: Note that that assumes that no employee appears in multiple departments' employee lists or multiple times in one departent's list.  If you cannot rely on that and therefore need to actively avoid double counting any `Employee` objects then you could collect the employee stream to a Set, and then re-stream the result (`.collect(Collectors.toSet()).stream()`).  Unlike collecting to a list and then re-streaming, that will actually have a useful effect under some circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

What you're getting is a compiler error, because `mapToInt` requires a `ToIntFunction` but you're providing none.

Also you don't need to collect the stream to a list only to convert it to a stream again. You can still use your stream as long as you don't call a terminal method.

So what you can do is something like this:

```
double average = company.getDepartments().stream()
        .flatMap(department -> department.getEmployees().stream())
        .map(Employee::getSalary)
        .filter(x -> x >= salaryLimit)
        .mapToDouble(salary -> salary)
        .average()
        .orElse(0.0);
```

`average()` gives you an `Optional<Double>` so you need to unwrap the value at the end. As a default value you can return `0.0` with a call to `orElse`

Comment: That's nearly workable, but you seem to be trying to map objects of type `List<Employee>` to objects of type `Integer` via a method belonging to type `Employee`.  That won't work.  You need to get the `Employee`s out of the lists, first.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Ah shoot, this is a list of `Employee`s, yes. Replaced one `map` with `flatMap` instead